# INSERT command denied to MariaDB user

Tags: database, mariadb

Hopefully someone can help me, when the developer queried to insert data, it gives the following error.

```
1142 - INSERT command denied to user 'db_user'@'localhost' for table 'table_name'
```

I checked user privileges, the user is granted for all the permissions:

```
MariaDB [(none)]> show grants for 'db_user'@'localhost';
+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Grants for db_user@localhost                                                                                |
+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| GRANT USAGE ON *.* TO `db_user`@`localhost` IDENTIFIED BY PASSWORD '*8FBC7CD05DD7354A9EAD92EC508E27E334FE'  |
| GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON `db`.* TO `db_user`@`localhost`                                                     |
+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

How can I resolve the issue?

Answer (score 1):

"[USAGE](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/grant/#the-usage-privilege) grants no real privileges". Its a confusing name. So more `GRANT` is needed:

```
GRANT INSERT ON dbname.table_name TO db_user@localhost;
```

Comment: Shouldn't `GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON 'db'.* TO 'db_user'@'localhost'` cover this?

Comment: It will. I assume I mentioned INSERT as it related to the question, and sometimes privileges get over-allocated in the name of simplicity.